# Turn off email notifications (not Gmail)

Tags: notifications, email

I have been getting email notifications from Gmail and the default email app on my Samsung Galaxy Exhibit. I only want to use Gmail but, when I go to uncheck "show notifications" for the default email app, I am unable to do so (it is grayed out). Why is this? I really don't need double notifications.

Comment: Why did you sign into the regular email app to start with? Can you simply sign out of it? You can also just disable the email app altogether.

Comment: I don't remember signing into it...if I did it was because I didn't realize there were two email apps. How do I disable it? I have tried hitting 'force stop', but it keeps on running...

Comment: right next to the 'force stop' button, there should be one that says disable. Otherwise I would try to go and look in your settings>accounts and remove the email account.

Comment: I found it! Accounts > Email > Settings > General Preferences > Priority Sender Inbox > Email notifications

Comment: @Jenna: If you found the solution and it isn't already listed, feel free to post your own answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. Disable the default email app - Settings>Apps>Email> "Disable"
2. Remove the email account - Settings>Accounts> "Remove the email account"

I'll add any other ways that I think of if I figure out other possible options to handle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open phone settings
2. Go to "Accounts/Account sync
3. Find your phone's email icon/widget.
4. Tap it, then tap the on "Remove Account."

Answer (score 0):

In the default E-mail App click settings, click on the account  turn/slide Notifications off for new E-mails. Android 7.0 Software H87110p AT&T Carrier Phone LG-H871

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gmail app

- Settings>Notifications>"Turn Off"

Or

Restart your device and try to turn off via Settings>Apps Info>Gmail and uncheck notifications.